# Does it not work vs Does not it work

Tags: meaning, word-order, negative-inversion

Do they mean same thing? I found both use on the Internet, for example:

> Why does it not work?

> Why does not it work?

Comment: The second one ("Why does not it work?") is wrong.  Remember that there are many people on the internet who are not native English speakers, or who made a typo when entering something.

Comment: We commonly say _Why doesn't it work?_, but when the words are spoken in full we always use _Why does it not work?_. You will see sentences like _Why does not it work?_ in old novels, but for some reason we never use that word order nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

*Why doesn't it work* is often used in the abbreviated form, but when not using this, you would use *Why does it not work*. *Why does not it work* is not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it not work?

> Why does not it work?

As commented and answered earlier, the first example is right.

[englishgrammar](https://www.englishgrammar.org/negative-questions/) explains further; 'contracted and uncontracted negative questions have different word order'.

> Doesn’t he understand? (Auxiliary verb + n’t + subject)
>
> Does he not understand? (Auxiliary verb + subject + not)